# use dynamic params for axios requests

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

```
axios.get("/api/session/" + this.roomId)
```

Above is a snippet from my axios call that uses my api.php route ('/api/session/{id} that loads through the controller the requested specific room => /api/session/3 is room 3).

Currently, this snippet is harcoded and always uses integer 1 for 'this.roomId'.
I did that, in oder to check if my vue is even working fine.

My question is now, how am I able to use a dynamic param for my prop roomId?

so I can always say something like

> .get/.post('url', $id) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing the roomId as a `prop` into the component then you need to handle the change in the parent component. For that I'd need a bit more context on where the room-ids come from and how you select the room-id there.

If you have this part down, then you'll want to watch changes on the roomId prop and re-fetch the data when ever it changes. You can do something like this in your room component:

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

const props: {
  roomId: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
}

export default {
  props,
  data() {
    return {
      room: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchRoom() {
     try {
       const response = await axios.get(`/api/session/${this.roomId}`)
       this.room = response.data
     } catch (err) {
       // - handle error
     }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    roomId: {
      immediate: true // so it's executed when component is created
      handler: function () {
        this.fetchRoom()
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, what info do u need? Currently I just use different single components that I registered in my app.js

Comment: You will need some wrapper component that will pass the roomId props to your room components and have a way to change the roomId there. With some kind of a drop down for example.

Comment: could u send me a link or something similar so I can grab a tutorial for this? I'm working with Laravel & PHP not for such a long time

Comment: If you're in Laravel you could just loop over your rooms array and pass the room id into vue component: `<room room-id="{{ $room->id }}"></room>` https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops