# Axios - send get request with url + variable

Tags: node.js, axios

This must be a stupid question, but I'm just starting and would appreciate any help!

So I have this code to get query parameter:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
var code = req.query.code;
console.log(code);
```

And when I go to http://localhost:3000/?code=123, I get the code value in console, so it works fine.

Now, I need to send a GET request and add the value of the var code, this is where I'm stuck.
Let's say, I should send a GET request to 'http://testtesttest123.com/' + var code + 'hi'.

How can I do this?

I've tried this way and some other ways, but nothing worked:

```
 axios.get('http://testtesttest123.com/?&code=', {params: {code}}, '&hi')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the final URL meant to look like? Is it `http://testtesttest123.com/?code=123&hi` or something else?

Comment: yes, exactly - http://testtesttest123.com/?code=123&hi

Comment: Multiple questions and answers related to this topic are already available. Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522972/use-dynamic-params-for-axios-requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `axios.get` call should look like this.

```
axios.get('http://testtesttest123.com/?code=' + code + '&hi')
```

With `code = 123`, this will call the URL `http://testtesttest123.com/?code=123&hi`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `params` config to send through query parameters. To support your empty `hi` parameter, you can include it in the URL string

```js
axios.get("http://testtesttest123.com/?hi", {
  params: { code }
})
```

For a `code` value of `123`, this will perform a GET request to

```
http://testtesttest123.com/?hi&code=123
```

It will also ensure that the `code` value is made safe for use in URLs